# scale up node in SQL Server always on

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL nodes in always on availability group (SQL on VM) with Availability Set configured. In case one node goes down and another node is not able to cater the application load, how to scale up additional database node in availability group?

What is the process we need to follow to scale additional node ASAP? How do we manage load until we spin up additional node?

[image]

Comment: are both nodes configured the same ..? i mean ,does they have same ram,cpu...

Comment: Yes, both nodes configured the same.

Comment: then i dont see any reason why second node was able to handle the load

Comment: Yes but this include risk of having only one node available. Idea here is to have at least two nodes available (may be one read-write and another read-only) and scale up the node if load increases.

Comment: http://www.davidklee.net/2012/06/10/add-new-node-to-sql-server-2012-alwayson-group/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think is the approach to overcome this situation.

1. Assume that your primary node (Node 1) goes down in SQL Server availability group, automatic failover would failover to the secondary replica node (Node 2). During the failover, the failover targets (Node 2) takes over the primary role and bring it online as the new primary database.
2. Assuming primary node (Node 1) which went down cannot be bring back immediately, add the additional replica to the availability group.
3. Start a new virtual machine with higher configuration (more CPU/RAM) with golden image (SQL server already installed)
4. Add newly created VM (Node 3) to the cluster
5. Restore the most recent full and transaction logs backup to it
6. Join it to the availability group and add it to the routing list
7. Manually failover to the newly created VM (Node 3) and make this node as primary
8. Make Node 2 which was primary earlier as secondary Node